# A connected maximal graph $G$ with no cycles of length at least $k+1$ has $|V(G)| \leq k$ or has a cut-vertex when $k \geq 2$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, connectedness, graph-connectivity

Is the following true:

*A maximal graph $G$ with no cycles of length at least $k+1$ has $|V(G)| \leq k$ or has a cut-vertex when $k \geq 2$.*

Here maximal is taken to mean that no edge can be added to $G$ without introducing a cycle of length at least $k+1$, we assume also that $G$ is connected. **Nota bene:** the statement might actually not be true but from trial and error I suspect that it is.

Obviously, when $|V(G)| \leq k$ such a maximal graph is the complete graph $K_{|V(G)|}$ which has no cut vertex.

Assume that $|V(G)| > k$ and that $G$ has no cycles of length at least $k+1$ and is maximal. I want to show that $G$ contains $K_k$ as an induced subgraph. Then, one of the vertices of this $K_k$ must be a cut-vertex.

By Menger's theorem, there exists $u,v\in V$ such that there are two disjoint paths $P_1$ and $P_2$ from $u$ to $v$. We have that 
\begin{equation}
|P_1| + |P_2| - 2\leq k,
\end{equation}
where $|P_1|$ counts the number of vertices in $P_1$. Now I want to show that the subgraph induced by $ P:= V(P_1) \cup V(P_2)$ is actually a complete graph. I think that I can then finish the argument. So, assume that some edge is missing between $v_1 \in P_1 $ and $v_2\in P_2$. As $G$ is maximal, the addition of the edge $v_1v_2$ would create a cycle $C$ of length at least $k+1$. Now, if this cycle is completely disjoint from $P \setminus \{v_1,v_2\}$, then we can use the two paths to find a cycle of lenght at least $k+1$ in the graph $G$ before adding the edge.

So assume that $C$ passes through some vertices in $P$. Now I do not know how to finish the argument as $C$ may pass through the vertices in $P_1$ and $P_2$ in any order switching back and forth between vertices in both paths and not encountering them in order. (How) Can the argument be finished?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the claim is false.  Consider $G$ to be the connected graph on $5$ vertices $a,b,c,d,e$ obtained by first constructing a complete bipartite $K_{2,3}$-graph with bipartition sets $\{a,b\}$ and $\{c,d,e\}$, and then adding an extra edge $\{a,b\}$.  This graph $G$ is maximal with respect to the condition that there does not exist a cycle of length $4+1$ (i.e., $k:=4$ here).  However, $G$ has more than $4$ vertices and does not have a cut vertex.

Comment: @Batominovski Thank you for the counterexample!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim is false for every integer $k\geq 4$, but it is easily seen to be true for $k\in\{2,3\}$.  For $k\geq4$, let $G$ be the connected graph on $n$ vertices $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n$, where $n>k$ is an integer, such that the vertex-induced subgraph $G[v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_{k-1}]$ is a complete graph on $k-1$ vertices, and that there are $2(n-k+1)$ extra edges $\{v_i,v_1\}$, $\{v_i,v_{k-1}\}$ for $i=k,k+1,k+2,\ldots,n$.  This graph is maximal with respect to the condition that there does not exist a cycle of length $k+1$, but $G$ has $n>k$ vertices and does not possess a cut vertex.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!